# Is there a command where I can teleport myself to a specific kind of block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't find my house and I have specific kind of blocks in it like beacons, enchantment tables, furnaces, stuff like that. I didn't put a bed and I never viewed the coordinates.

Comment: Beacons, in plural? I respect you if this isn't a world with cheats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Finding my house in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft) (XY problem)

Answer (score 3):

Is this a world with cheats? If it is a world with cheats, set it so you cant lose your inventory using:

> /gamerule keepInventory true

and then do /kill. This will send you to your spawnpoint, which is hopefully near your home

Personally, I frown upon using cheats in a survival world, along with intentionally dying. If you are not using cheats and the bed is valid or your house is near your spawnpoint, find iron and redstone by digging underground to make a compass.

Also, if you have access to paper (crafted using sugarcane) you can make a map.  These can be expanded by surrounding them with paper on a crafting table. If you find oddly coloured areas, they may indicate certain structures such a your house, or perhaps even a village.

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to do what you wanted. But nevertheless you could try [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/), which is an advanced world editing software, and fly around until you find your house. You could then use the *Set Player Position* tool, to move your player.
But make sure to close Minecraft, as there may occur permanent damage to your world, if you leave Minecraft and MCEdit running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a command to do this, but there is one to move you to a specific position using `/tp <x> <y> <z>`.

Answer (score 0):

So they're is a way you can get coordinates back to your base. For Windows users:

1. Go into your %appdata%
2. Click you .minecraft folder
3. Click open the "Logs" folder
4. Scroll to the bottom of the folder and find "Latest"
5. Once you find it, open it with Notepad or whatever you prefer. Me personally, I would choose Notepad.
6. Once the document is opened, look for ANY coordinates in form.

Try as many coordinates that you are able to find in that document. Hopefully, one of the coordinates work. If not, follow the next steps.

---

My steps didn't Work? For Windows users,

1. Make sure your in your logs folder in your .mincraft folder. If not, follow direction #'s 1-3 from my previous instructions.
2. Once your in your "Logs" folder, open the very first document at the top there.
3. Find and Try any coordinates in that folder as well.
4. If non work, then go to the next document in the folder your Logs folder. Open that one up, then find and try any in there. If non are there, go to the next document in the folder and so on but make sure your coordinates aren't from other servers. It should say the server you joined or it may show server chat on some of the document.

Hope this helps!