# How do I keep my inventory after death in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm always playing Minecraft PE on my tablet, but I got lost and my plan to get home involves me dying and respawning at home. I have diamonds in my inventory and I don't want to lose them, but the command won't work. Is there another way for me to keep my inventory after I die?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the two methods, commands and enderchests, don't exist. However, you could craft a compass with iron and redstone, and follow it home. Or you could wait for future updates for them to add one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to die. Use methods to get home. Some are found in this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft).

In summary, these are the methods that are relevant to your case:

1. Maps
2. Compasses
3. Giant pillar
4. Abandonment (Build a new home)
5. Make a chest near a landmark, then kill yourself.
6. Copy of world (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

by command I'm assuming you mean `/gamerule keepInventory True`

What I suggest you do is make a chest containing your items, and place it in such a way you will have no problem finding it back, then kill your player

Comment: Commands do not work in Minecraft Pocket Edition.