# Lost Coordinates In Creative

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was making a server world, so I made a teleportation pad (/tp command). I chose a random coordinate far from the spawn so no one would see it. So I built the best house that I have ever built, with a lockable door and everything. I was about to do a YouTube video about it. But then my Minecraft crashed. Every time I went on ANY world, including a new world it crashed. I'm on Windows 10 so I searched up if people had the same problem as me. They said to go back to 1.8.9. I did, and the command blocks reset so i lost the coordinates.

Comment: What exactly are you asking, a way to get the coordinates from your tp pad? Can you think of any other way to write your question to be a bit more clear matey?

Comment: @Oak I mean that I lost the coordinates to my builds area. Because I made a thing that teleports you to the builds area. But I LOST the coordinates to the builds. And I really worked hard on it.

Comment: Do you have the console logs from that day? They include chat and commands.

Comment: I do, but how do you check those?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding my house in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access your logs through your minecraft files:

**C:\Users\GiraRay\AppData\Roaming\ .minecraft\logs** *(remove the space in Roaming\ .minecraft !)*

Here, you can see a list of winRAR files and txt. documents named after dates of every play session. Each file should contain everything displayed in the chat and every command executed, by cmd blocks and players.

Unless you remember when you built that house, it's going to be a pain to navigate the right file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to external tools? I'm fairly certain that the only way is with MCEdit or comparable. I solved a simalar problem by going into chunk view, and looked for where the chunks were generated: where I had been.

Comment: I have MCEdit 2, but I don't know how to use it. Sorry I'm not that good at those stuff.

Comment: There should be a button that says 'chunk view'. press it and look around until you find an area of generated terrain. see if your house is in it. if not, repeat.