# I lost my house in minecraft. How can I find it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was in creative mode on minecraft PE. I made this really awesome house plus a hotel! I was finishing up my house but decided to explore first. I explored for about 10 minutes and then stopped. Suddenly, I started worrying because I didn't know where I was. I couldn't find my house on a map, a compass, and I didn't make a beacon or keep track of what side of the sun it was on either. How can I find my house again???

Comment: I just am desperately needing help with this issue! That house was awesome, i mean it! It was a mansion and took me over a month to build! Please help me!

Comment: Was the last bed you rested in one from the mansion? If you kill your character, you'll respawn wherever it was you last rested.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft?rq=1 Related but not about PE so some answers may not be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I don't know how to die in minecraft PE in creative. Could you please leave another message telling me how?

Comment: Do I just change it to survival?

Comment: I'm flagging this as a duplicate of [I lost my house in creative mode](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/259635/142044)

Comment: @HaylaMills If you dig deep enough (past bedrock), you can fall into the void, which will kill you.

Comment: @pushasha no you can't anymore there's an invisible border at the bottom of the void.

Comment: @Alex Darn! Thanks for the update :/

Comment: @pushasha http://imgur.com/1xWwHht http://imgur.com/wOYoQ4i

Answer (score 2):

A 3rd party solution:

You could download a map viewer that loads a Minecraft save and renders the entirety of the world in a 2d layout. Then, remember a biome that was either close or home to where your  mansion was (for example, was it in the taiga biome, desert biome, etc.), then look in that area.

Some map viewers allow you to scan a map for particular objects, like chests and other items. So since you made a flat grassy world, you would need to look for items like chests, wood stairs, the blocks you put in you mansion and you should be able to find it.

Comment: The only thing is, I made it the flat world. So it was just a grassy, flat world.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry For any missed spell word nor random letter I don’t have my glasses on Most of the time you can fly straight up and fly around for a bit then if you check the ground every now and then you should  see or you an have someone  join then f you have host privaga then teleport to them that should get near where you spawn sorry if that doesn’t work for you or if you don’t have that option