# I lost my house in creative mode

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was in creative mode on Minecraft PE, and decided to build a really awesome house to live in.

After I was done with my house, I decided I would just explore for a bit. I didn't realize that I had walked too far from my house that I had completely lost it! It wasn't on a map, and I didn't keep track of which side of a compass it was on!

Is there any way to find my house again?
I really need help trying to find my house again! Please help me find it!

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to go about your Minecraft world and find it.

1. Go to the world settings
2. Change game mode to Survival
3. Save
4. Play the world
5. Find a place where you can die (Like a dark cave with zombies in it)
6. If you built your house anywhere you spawned, you should find it.
7. Exit and save
8. Goto world settings
9. Change game mode to creative
10. Save
11. There you go.

---

Or... If it's a superflat world...

1. Goto your world
2. Build a really high tower
3. Goto step number 1 at the top and follow the rest of the steps.