# Went to the Nether, got lost, and lost my castle!

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I made a castle on Minecraft Pocket Edition that was far away from the place that I spawned. Once I had made my castle, I went to the Nether and got lost. I made a new Nether portal, went through, and ended up at a completely different portal than the one I made at the castle. Now I'm lost. I have used the compass to get back to the place that I spawned, but I still need to get back to my castle. I'm in creative mode.

Comment: Hmm, what causes you to not just drop a bed and change your spawn?  I mean... why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lost my house in minecraft. How can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259571/i-lost-my-house-in-minecraft-how-can-i-find-it)

Answer (score 1):

You should go into survival mode,  turn on keep inventory, go to the nether, and kill yourself. You should NOT sleep while you're lost, or else when you die, you will be sent back to where you've last slept.

If this doesn't work, you could try building another castle. If you don't want to do that, try to create a map and if you don't see your castle on the map, fly somewhere farther away from your portal. You should keep creating new maps and spiraling away from your spawnpoint. You can do this without using maps, too. Eventually you should find your castle.

Answer (score 0):

One block in the Nether counts as four blocks in the Overworld, so you have traveled an even longer distance. I recommend that you go back to the Nether and find your original portal.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest committing suicide in survival mode to get you back to your spawn point and then turn back to creative

Comment: This solution means you have to make sure that he actually slept in a bed in that castle, or that he set his spawn point in his castle.

Comment: Being able to change gamemode would imply commands are available, at which point it's easier to use `/kill` instead.