# Help! My son lost the portal in the Nether and can't get back to his world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son got lost in the Nether  and can't find the portal back to his world. He tried building another portal but it didn't take him back. He's using the app on an iPad and I have no clue on how to help him, he's pretty devastated and thinks everything is lost forever.

Comment: He's not on Hardcore, is he?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Went to the Nether, got lost, and lost my castle!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270344/went-to-the-nether-got-lost-and-lost-my-castle)

Comment: The options will depend on his specific world.  If it's near the spawn or he slept in a bed, a [compass](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Compass) will point towards it.

Comment: I don't see a compass on his screen. He was in creative mode. My Minecraft knowledge is practically zero.

Comment: If he's in creative mode, he should be able to spawn a compass.  Did his new/second portal take him back to the overworld at all?

Comment: @Malady Hardcore doesn't exist on MCBE.

Comment: @JWolf Does your son's game have "Show Coordinates" on?

Comment: In mcje I have found my base using region files and or world edit, but nowadays I store all my coordinates on a files inside the world save.

Answer (score 1):

Since in the comments, you've mentioned that your son was playing in Creative mode, he could go in the world options and enable cheats, enable keep inventory (it'll be a game-rule setting in the world options), then go into the in-game chat and type in the command `/kill @s` and your son will respawn back at where his last spawn point would be.

As for the failed Nether portal, make sure that it's the right size (the minimum size for a portal is four obsidian blocks wide and five obsidian blocks tall), like this:

```
O = Obsidian, X = Air

O O O O
O X X O
O X X O
O X X O
O O O O
```

and you light the portal with a fire source of course (flint & steel, and fire charges should do alright, though ghast and blaze fireballs can also light the portal), if the construction of the portal doesn't work even after that then it's likely a temporary glitch in the game and it may be fixed in a future update.

Comment: By failed nether portal I think OP means that he built it in a different place so it too him somewhere else.