# Unable to locate house in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son has spent a long time making a big house in creative mode of Minecraft and now someone else has played in that world and he can't navigate back to his house. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you know if he had a bed in his house which he slept in? Beds act as a respawn point in the game but only if the player has slept in it at least once. If this is the case simply dying would respawn him back at his house. Although he would lose everything he has on him.
-Edit: Just saw this was creative, seeing as how you cant die in creative, disregard this comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lost my house in minecraft. How can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259571/i-lost-my-house-in-minecraft-how-can-i-find-it)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do relocate your build:

1. Let's say that your build was not too far from spawn, and the person that went on this map flew you far away, then it would just be a simple `/tp @p 0 100 0` command that you could execute. This method could also work if you remember around where the build was, let's say it was around 300 blocks from spawn, execute `/tp @p 0 100 0` then face the direction of your build and do `/tp @p ~ ~ 100` (This may not work for PE)
2. If your build was in a completely random location, you will need to follow this method:

   1. On your computer, download a software that can view the files of your iPad, I recommend [iExplorer](http://macroplant.com/iexplorer)
   2. Download [MCedit](http://www.mcedit.net/)
   3. Navigate to your "saves" folder as follows: `Apps -> com.mojang.minecraftpe -> Documents -> games -> com.mojang -> minecraftWorlds -> <worldname>` Substituting `<worldname>` for the name of your world.
   4. Copy `level.dat` in a folder that you can access on your computer (such as desktop)
   5. Run MCedit using the `level.dat` that you just copied.
   6. Locate your world there: You can use the block search function to look for specific builds, or search for "non-natural blocks" Refer to [this](http://mcedit2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on how to find you build on MCedit.
   7. Copy down the coordinates, and paste that into you tp command like this `/tp @p X Y Z` Substituting X Y Z for the appropriate number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good method. Use a compass. Follow the compass’ needle and you should find your house. But there’s a small catch. For this to work, your house needs to be close to where you first spawned in that world.