# Is there a way to teleport to a type of specific block in Minecraft in Windows 10 Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I lost my house and buildings, and spawned very far away. Luckily, my house is rather gaudy, with an enchantment table, crying obsidian; the works. Many, many hours into this world and really don't want to start over. I broke my bed while remodeling and forgot to replace it... **Is there a command to teleport to a certain type of block in Minecraft Windows 10 Edition? And if so, what is it?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lost my house in minecraft. How can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259571/i-lost-my-house-in-minecraft-how-can-i-find-it) (cutting out the XY problem and addressing the actual issue)

Comment: It wouldn't really help them out much though, since they don't really say anything that would be helpful to the OP's situation

Comment: First off, I don't see how the answer to that question wouldn't be helpful here. Second off, even if that were true, it is irrelevant, as both questions are clearly asking the same thing and all you are saying is that the duplicate target has an incomplete set of answers.

Comment: Just as a tip, use `/gamerule showcoordinates true` so you know where you are now, and so you know where your house is when you find it. Cheats are not needed and is perfectly fine to do.

Comment: Are you wondering how to travel faster or how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

If you built your house close to the world spawn point, you could get a compass and it'd point you to the world's initial spawn point.

Alternatively if you used a compass on a lodestone block, then that particular compass will point you to the lodestone it was used on.

Edit 2-13-21:
Alternatively, if you had pets at your base you could try to teleport to them.

My memory of the command may be a bit rusty, so someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong;
/tp @s  @r[type=wolf] in this example, you should be able to teleport to any random possible wolf in the world, including eventually teleporting to any wolves you've tamed.

Comment: I would assume by the fact he spawned far away from his house that he is near world spawn right now.... That being said, what you said makes sense.