# Unable to respawn at intended location

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am in creative mode and I want to respawn at my house. I tried the `/kill` command and it said "killed Steve" but I'm still in the void.

Can you help? I am very frustrated and aggravated at this point. I created a big house and I want to get back to it but can't figure out how.

Comment: A good starting point would be [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft) about locating one's house. A compass may or may not be useful here, but if all else fails loading the world up in an editor will work

Comment: If you're playing on a PC, you can hit F3 and go back to the original spawn point which has coordinates close to X=0, Y=0, Z=0.
If you're saying you're in The End, instead of clipped out of bounds, you need to kill the dragon first in order to teleport back without commands (assuming you're playing vanilla)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in creative mode, you have a few options.

- Since you said `/kill` didn't work, and instead killed a generic Steve, you could try `/kill @e[type=Player]`. This kills all players on the server.
- You can also try `/tp 0 100 0`, which teleports you above your spawn area. This would work in any dimension (overworld/nether/end), so you can hopefully locate a familiar landmark that leads back to your house.
- Digging straight down into the void should kill all players, including those in creative mode. You can then respawn.
- If none of these work, you can use an external map editor and adjust your player position back to your house.