# Please help find way back to house on Minecraft on iOS

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My daughter has spent a long time making a big house in creative mode of Minecraft in iOS on her iPad and now someone else has played in that world and she can't navigate back to his house. Can anyone help?

She did go into survival mode and killed herself and re spawned but it didn’t take her back to her house. She had already made a new bed where she was. She has destroyed that bed and tried again but it keeps taking her back to that spot and not her house.

I seen a similar thread and followed the instructions of downloading iexplorer and I located the level.dat file. I then tried to download the MCEdit but it won’t run properly. I have windows 10 so that could be issue.

I’m not sure how to get MCEdit to run properly and then how to open the level.dat file to then try and find the house to get co-ordinates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as she is very upset and wants to find her house again.

My son has teleported into her world but wasn’t beside her. She went to him in her world but was so far away couldn’t find her house again. She does have the big light beacons at her house but can’t see them.

She also had a map of the house and seen a video that showed how to make map bigger and show location or where you are to where your house is but her house was not on the map.

She also does not have another world it is only this one world so her house is somewhere in it.

Please help!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding my house in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft). Have you seen this, Sharonn? There are many answers there, I hope one will help your daughter and you out.

Comment: If it happens that you cannot find it, could you leave a world dowload link?

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of MCEdit: the classic version at https://www.mcedit-unified.net/ and the new version that is in the process of being rewritten at https://www.mcedit.net/. Be sure to try both.

When you find her house, note the coordinates. In the game, run the `/tp (x) (y) (z)` command with the coordinates of her house to teleport her to that location. Then, type `/setworldspawn` to change the default world spawn point, and use a bed to set the player’s spawn point.