# I lost my Minecraft house

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So a while back I built a modern house on a mountain side. After I finished that house I decided to build another house in a different biome. I used creative mode to fly around and find a place to build a new house. Then I didn't play for like half a year. I came back, finished my second house, and wanted to go back to my first house in the mountains, but I totally forgot what direction it was in. I just remember some distinct features about the area. I flew around in creative mode for a while, but I still can't find it :(

Comment: Try using a map to map all the area around your house. When you have filled the map but not found your other house, then craft a bigger map then try and fill that in. The idea is to eliminate all the areas that you have already searched. If your house is big enough then it may appear on the map before you reach it. Do you want to use normal means to locate this house, or are you prepared to use external mapping software, such as Minutor?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/29516/143571

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding my house in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using MCedit to find your base.

Usually spawn chunks are around 0,0 so find the chunks with generated terrain to find your house. MCEdit has a previously explored chunk finder, so the area around your house will be a big blob and the are you for over will look like thick lines.

If your house is on the surface, the top down view will help you spot it easily. Else MCedit also can search for particular blocks to help you find your base.

If you built right at spawn you can go back with /kill (remember to save the coordinates of the second house this time!).

Answer (score -1):

How far did you travel from the world spawn before building the old house?

Assuming it wasn't extremely far, it should be within a couple thousand blocks from spawn. Use the F3 debug screen to find your location and coordinates, write that down so you don't lose the location of your *new* house, then travel to 0,0. If you still don't recognize the location, place a bed, sleep in it then break that bed, pack your gear into a chest, kill yourself, and you'll land a couple hundred blocks away from 0,0 in a place you will most certainly know because you started the game right there. Go back to get your gear, then either travel to your house if you recall the route, or just explore in expanding spiral.

Also, if you did build a Nether portal near your old house, you can build a new one, go to the Nether, and explore around (just don't get lost there!) - you're likely to find your old portal to the house much easier, with distances being 1/8 of overworld.

If you are an avid traveler though, and your old home was tens of thousands blocks from spawn, things get much trickier.

Open your save in the .minecraft folder, find the subfolder 'region' and sort the files within by modification date. Find the oldest with date that corresponds to your date of departure from the old house, check the name, it will be something like r.-7.8.mca - generally two numbers, r.[x].[y].mca. Enter it in [Coordinate Tools](https://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/coordinates/) and you'll get the coordinates a 512x512 area where anything happened last at the time the file date indicates. You may try other files around or a bit before that date and you should eventually find a region you recognize.