# I have reset my world spawn to a distant place. how can I get back to the original world spawn area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I teleported far away from my house using `/locate`. I went to a stronghold and set my spawn there thinking I might die several times. After defeating the dragon, I realized that I couldn't find my house. I was in the middle of nowhere, and even my map (made to the largest possible size) didn't show anything. Now I can't find my old house, which took me over 11 hours to make. Compasses won't work since I reset my world spawn. Is there any possible way to find my house, or is there no chance?

I am in creative mode.

Comment: Was you creative mode house near world spawn?

Comment: Can you just use `/kill`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding my house in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft)

Comment: I'm not confident about my answer, but maybe try locating the house from a 2,500 block radius from 0,0 XZ? If you spent 11 hours on it, it must be a very large base. If you remember the biome you built it in, looking for it can be sped up. It is quite unrealistic for anyone to travel more than 100,000 blocks just to build a house in creative singleplayer.

Comment: @pppery Most of answers there are either irrelevant here (world spawn was reset) or way obsolete (mapping tools from 2011)

Comment: ...and next time don't touch world spawn unless you really know what you're doing. Just use beds or respawn anchors.

Comment: Questions with outdated answers do not cease to be valid duplicate targets. There should only be one question for "I got lost and need to find my house", not two.

Comment: @pppery This one boils down to "I lost my world spawn resetting it to a distant place", which has quite a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

Press F3, and find your current coordinates, and the "Facing" entry, then face towards 0,0 - if your X coordinate is positive, turn "Facing ... (negative x)", similarly angle yourself for 'z' and just head in direction of 0,0. The original spawn is usually within ~200 blocks from there. If you still have trouble locating it after arriving at (0,0), you can use /seed to get the world seed, create a new world with that seed, and then check the coordinates where you spawn in that world. After that you'll have to use your memory of the terrain to find your builds.

Comment: Do coordinates change when the world spawn is changed? I thought it was relative to the centre of the world.

Comment: @Corsaka Actually, you are right... I've completely misremembered that - I was convinced with Hermitcraft 6, coords were moved with spawn to vicinity of the spawn island... it appears - not. This whole answer needs a total rewrite...