# Minecraft world backup - How do I find builds easily?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I have a backup of my server which was recently hacked. I have lots of builds there; the main problem is that all the builds in that world backup are scattered which makes them very hard to find.

How can I convert it to a world map from which I can find my builds easily and continue my work? Is there a tool or mod which can allow this?

Comment: The Dynmap plugin (https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/dynmap%C2%AE.274/) could come in handy. It shows you a "Google maps" style view of the world.

Comment: From my experience, Dynmap is very poor at finding scattered builds. I tried to use it to find all builds of a prolific player on a server limited to 5000x5000; I found a couple, but kept finding new ones while wandering on foot, for months afterwards. Caves converted into natural-looking shrines, forest converted into a park, a house tucked inside jungle, a hobbit-style village - anything not blatantly intrusive is very hard to spot.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I eventually found out a mod that basically renders all the chunks in a server (because the server I had my backup in was very slow) 
It is the journey map mod that helped me, you can find it on curseforge if you have similar kind of query

Comment: Note that the OP asks "How can I convert it to a world map from which I can find my builds easily and continue my work?" - not exclusively for a tool or mod. This feels similar to questions about problems with Bethesda games turning out to only be able to be solved by mods. Vote to Leave Open.

Comment: @Joachim This was edited; the original version I close voted was a clear tool rec. This is also a borderline duplicate of [Finding my house in Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/29516/185203), for what it's worth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding my house in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft)