# Can't find where the original part of my world is

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

My original world was made on the Xbox360 version years ago. I took the save file and converted it so it would be compatible with the Java version I now have, and it worked! I can get to the world, however...  It dropped me in the middle of nowhere and I can't find the original part of the world. I know it's there *somewhere* as this isn't the first world I moved over and I found where the other one was.
I surrounded the original part of the world with glowstone so I would be able to point it out and find it immediately, but its been 3 years and I still can't find the original part of my world.
Is there something that can search for a specific block that I could use? Because like I said, when I started the world up on Java, it just dropped me in the middle of nowhere, who knows how far away.

Note: I am **not** looking for my house, I could find that easily, I'm looking for a whole aft Xbox world that was converted to Java.

Comment: probably a duplicate. see [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392938/minecraft-world-backup-how-do-i-find-builds-easily), and [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Replace the word "house" with whatever it is you are trying to find in your world.  The duplicate link still applies.  An external editor is probably your best bet which that link goes over I believe.